# Julia traversing the expression tree containing broadcast results in unintended tuples

Tags: tuples, julia, metaprogramming

I am trying to understand Metaprogramming in Julia. I wrote the following
code

```
function traversal!(x::Expr,mem)
    for xx in x.args
        if isa(xx,Expr)
            push!(mem,xx)
            traversal!(xx,mem)
        end
    end
end

expr=:(sum((x-cos(W2*sin(W1*x+b1)+b2))^2))
mem=[]
a=traversal!(expr,mem)
```

I expect mem to be

- :((x - cos(W2 * sin(W1 * x + b1) + b2)) ^ 2)
- :(x - cos(W2 * sin(W1 * x + b1) + b2))
- :(cos(W2 * sin(W1 * x + b1) + b2))
- :(W2 * sin(W1 * x + b1) + b2)
- :(W2 * sin(W1 * x + b1))
- :(sin(W1 * x + b1))
- :(W1 * x + b1)
- :(W1 * x)

Result is as expected however when i replace the expression

`expr=:(sum((x-cos(W2*sin(W1*x+b1)+b2))^2))`

with

`expr=:(sum((x-cos.(W2*sin.(W1*x+b1)+b2)).^2))`

output becomes

- :((x - cos.(W2 * sin.(W1 * x + b1) + b2)) .^ 2)
- :(x - cos.(W2 * sin.(W1 * x + b1) + b2))
- :(cos.(W2 * sin.(W1 * x + b1) + b2))
- :((W2 * sin.(W1 * x + b1) + b2,))
- :(W2 * sin.(W1 * x + b1) + b2)
- :(W2 * sin.(W1 * x + b1))
- :(sin.(W1 * x + b1))
- :((W1 * x + b1,))
- :(W1 * x + b1)
- :(W1 * x)

Why do i get those extra Tuple Symbols?